# Windows 7: Preserve upper screen space for virtualbox taskbar

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I've a VirtualBox running in seamless mode, and I find it annoying that maximized windows applications get o top the xfce task bar. 
Is there a way to tell windows not to use or occupy the upper screen space?

Thank you.

Comment: Move the taskbar in lower portion.

Comment: I understand you mean to move the xfce taskbar to the bottom. I've tried with no effect.

Comment: What I've seen is that the current windows window ;) DOES resize to make room to the taskbar (doesn't matter if the xfce taskbar is on the top or bottom). But as soon as I switch to another maximized windows app, the app window overlaps the xfce taskbar.